# Send an Android Notification before an Activity has been launched

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-notifications

**EDIT: The problem below disappeared with no changes in code.  The notifications started appearing properly upon later reboots.  This is at most an intermittent issue.**

I have an application that starts up a background service when the phone boots.  After a certain event is detected, I would like to send a notification to the user, allowing the user to elect to start my MainActivity if the user taps on the notification.

The problem is that Android seems to disallow sending notifications if no Activity has yet been launched.  The code below is in a custom `android.app.Application` class, and works only if the Activity has already been launched.

Is there any way to send a Notification before an Activity has been launched?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Event Detected")
                .setContentText("Tap to launch MainActivity")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Here is the error:

```
05-20 09:09:42.084: W/ContextImpl(801): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1505 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.sendNotification:981 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.addNotification:670 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$7.run:2142 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:733
```

Comment: Don't send it from the `Application`, send it from the `Service`.

Comment: You might also cull the `TaskStackBuilder` stuff and see if that helps, if switching to using the `Service` as your `Context` does not help.

Comment: May be it is because the OS components responsible for creating and rendering a notification, have not been initialized by the the time your code makes a call to it. May be you can try sending a notification in a infinite while loop, and break the loop if the code does not enter the catch block. Hope you understand what I am trying to suggest.

Comment: Could it be related to the context you are using to create the notification/start the activity? As explained here - http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: As a test, I tried putting the same code in both the Application and the Service to test the suggestion of @323go, and to my surprise both notifications displayed.  When I reverted this change, the code above started working in the original location.

Comment: It could be an intermittent timing issue as @eu-dr suggests.  The context is unchanged, so apparently there is nothing wrong with using the Application as the context.