# How to send push notification to an android device before an application is opened means none of the activity is launched even once?

Tags: android, push-notification

When none of the activity is launched even once,i want to send a push notification to the user.
For example, once user installs application but doesnt open then a notification is pushed that please use the application.
Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. How would the user call the registration process for the push messages if he never ran the app itself? Until he does, the app is considered to be in a stopped state and you can't interact with it unless you have another app installed that would "start" it.

Comment: okay..Is there any other method which could start my application in background without opening app and push notifications can be called ?       I read this discussion its related to what  i am saying.but couldnt get anything so.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809158/send-an-android-notification-before-an-activity-has-been-launched

Comment: The app cannot start itself while it is in a stopped state, so no. No broadcast receivers work, so don't try that either.

Comment: You would need another app to start your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a background service on application level and registering on gcm server and other process so even if app is not used you can send notification as your service has registered your device with gcm id on your server.Call api for registering device to your server from your GCMIntentService class.

Comment: you can start it in your application, but read the question... it was never yet started

Comment: Yes application needs to be launched once in this case.If user launches splash screen only and after that not using app in this case this will be helpful.